# Error building tesseract for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract

Im trying to use Tesseract on Google Glass, but I havent been able to build my project.
I built Tesseract using the following:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two
$ cd tess-two/tess-two
$ ndk-build
$ android update project --path . --target android-19
$ ant release
```

Afterwards, I imported the module from Android Studio, and added a dependency to that module from the module in which I'm building the app. If I build the tesstwo module from Android Studio the build is finished successfully.

However, when I try to build my app´s module, I get the following error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:compileDebugJava, :tesstwo:compileDebugJava]
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:tesstwo:compileLint
:tesstwo:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:preBuild
:tesstwo:preReleaseBuild
:tesstwo:checkReleaseManifest
:tesstwo:prepareReleaseDependencies
:tesstwo:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:compileReleaseNdk
/home/mateo/repos/POC7_OCR/tesstwo/src/main/jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/pageiterator.cpp:19:26: fatal error: pageiterator.h: No such file or directory
 #include "pageiterator.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

The file pageiterator.h is indeed there, and permissions are given. I think the problem might be in how NDK is looking for the files it should be building, but I've never used it before and cant seem to get where the problem might be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look there, may help about the integration with Gradle : 
https://coderwall.com/p/eurvaq